# if without else and else with return;

Tags: if-statement, return

I would love to know is there difference between this code:

```
if(some condition) {some code} else {return;}
```

and this code:

```
if(some condition) {some code}
```

Both if are same only one without else and other with else {return;}
I am confused since this return; does not return any value, is it just leave this block of code or do something else?

Comment: Depends on the rest of the code: If something is following the IF and should be skipped, then statement 1 has a different effect than statement 2

Comment: The return statements for [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17) and [C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84.aspx) both exit the method that contains the return statement (not just the block that contains it).  If your return statement does not contain a value that implies that the containing method returns void - otherwise you would have got a compile error when you tried to return without a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary difference between your 2 `if` statements is as follows

In the 1st case, i.e. in case of `if` with `else` clause that says `return`, if the code execution enters the `else` part, then it would terminate at `return` and return to the caller -- which could be another method or function.

In the 2nd case, i.e. in case of `if` with no `else`, regardless of whether the `if` condition evaluates to `true` or `false`, the code execution would continue to the end of the method or program and then return to the caller -- unless you have a return within the `if` condition's `...some code` section, in which case the code execution will terminate and return to the caller.

If we take a broader example to highlight the differences.

#### Case 1:

```
// beginning of code block
{
    if(some condition) 
    {
        // some code
    } 
    else 
    {
        return;
    }
    // ... some more code
} // end of the method / code block
```

In this case,  `... some more code will never be executed if the` if`condition evaluates to`false`.

#### Case 2:

```
// beginning of code block
{
    if(some condition) 
    {
        // some code
    } 
    // ... some more code
} // end of the method / code block
```

In this case, `... some more code will be always executed regardless of whether the` if`condition evaluates to`true`or`false`... unless you have a return within the` if` condition, in which case , as stated earlier in case 1, code execution will return to the calling method / function.

Comment: Thank you Shiva, your answer completely resolve my question.

Answer (score 0):

The else portion is the difference. judging by you setup, I would say that the first one is basically saying if condition TRUE-execute code ELSE return FALSE. the second one is saying if condition is TRUE execute code. which means if the condition is FALSE it would not return a FALSE value.